# How do I solve CORS error on Spring boot + Nuxt.js

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, cors, nuxt.js

Trying to fix this CORS error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/login' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3001/api/demo/signup') from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I set the proxy and also webConfig for allowing cors and there's no change. Here are the codes.

nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources', // scss
    '@nuxtjs/bulma'
  ],

  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    debug: true,
    credenitals: true,
    retry: { retries: 3 },
  },
  
  proxy: {
      '/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:9000',
          pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''},
          changeOrigin: true // accept cross origin  
      },
  },

   server: {
    port: 3001, 
  },
```

signUp.vue

```
  async save(){
    console.log('data chk', this.data)
    const params = this.data
    await axios.post('/api/demo/signup', {params})
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('result', result)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    });
  },
```

Application.java

```
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication 
// @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hello Kuroe!");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowCredentials(true)
    .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3001")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE")
                .maxAge(3000);
    }
    };
    }

}
```

Controller.java

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    private DemoService demoService;

    @CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*")
    @PostMapping("/api/demo/signup")
    public String write(DemoDto demoDto) {
        log.debug("signup={}", demoDto);
        demoService.savePost(demoDto);
        return "done";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should check @CrossOrigin annotation.

More information about a CORS support in Spring Framework you can find on [spring.io website](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) or check [an article here.](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors)